# Creating logic gate for minimum comparison

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, mips

Is there any way to create a (simple) logic gate to compare two integers which are stored in a temporary register?

Edit: It's okay for just one-digit long integers.

Comment: If the integers are one bit wide, then you can compare them with a single two-input gate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here is a representation of a 7485 4-bit magnitude comparator:

[image]

They can be cascaded to create as large of a comparator as necessary:

[image]